# Stretching and overflow in jasper reports title band

Tags: jasper-reports, overflow

I have a few fields on the right side of my title band. The name of the patient can be quite large, so I need that specific field to push everything else down:

[image: Textfields in a "grid"]

I did set the fields to float with no effect....

Comment: make sure all the objects under the name of the patient are set to float as they will be moving down when the name stretches.  on the patient name field make sure you have checked the *Stretch with over flow* check box